# .NET Core 3.0: Warning CS8632 The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0

I get this warning when I try to use a nullable reference type like so:

```
using System;

namespace DotNetCoreExperiment
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            string? fred = null; // warning occurs here
            Console.WriteLine(fred);
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this warning and how can I fix it? I did enable `<NullableReferenceTypes>true</NullableReferenceTypes>` in my csproj file. I don't want to do `#nullable enable` on every code file!

Comment: Do you have a `LangVersion` attribute?

Comment: Use `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`  instead. `NullableReferenceTypes` was removed a long time ago. Did you use an old blog post for reference instead of the [update docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)  perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos aha, that was it! Thanks! If you could post that as an answer that would be great. Now I wonder why this setting is not easily accessible via the project properties page...

Comment: Because this is a non-trivial change for existing code. Once you enable it, you'll start getting warnings or errors from all files in a solution. In a multi-project solution people would have to stop doing anything else and start fixing errors. By combining `#nullable` and the project setting though people can upgrade one file at a time and still be able to deploy

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but looks relevant to my issue. I am using .net5.0 and have  <Nullable>enable</Nullable> in my csproj, when running locally I don't see any issue, but in azure devops pipeline, I get this warning  Warning CS8632. Any ideas why it might be the case?